# Laravel 8 - Share 2 tables from database in one controller?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

It's more of a logical question than code...

So I have 2 tables in the DB: `kpiInvoices` and `kpiTerms`

[image]

The `kpiInvoices` table is where the user's entered data will be saved to and displayed in a DataTable.

[image]

When the user creates a new KPI invoice it will show the form above. I want the `SLA Term` to be `<select>` and fetches the data from the `kpiTerms` Table. When the user selects a term, the `Cost` input automatically fetches and show the cost of that selected term. Then submits the form and saves the data in `kpiInvoices` table.

- Do I need to create relationships for the 2 tables?
- Should I use Eloquent Relationships?
- Should I `use App\Models\KPITerms` in the `KPIInvoiceController` and do a foreach loop in the blade?

Comment: No need for relation in this form, maybe after. just get KPITerms::all() and loop through it to display the select option. With some javascript onChange event of that select you can fetch the price of the item selected

Comment: Instead of KPITerms::all() you can get the specific cost using ajax. Use onChnage (jquery) and send the term id to the ajax controller in the ajax controller fetch the specific term and return the cost to the ajax function. On success put the cost on the cost input field.

Answer (score 0):

So I made an ajax request to both SLATerm and SLACost and looped through the requested data. Then I made an if statement within the loop to change the SLACost based on the SLATerm selected.

```
function fetchSLA() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/management/kpi/fetch/sla",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response.SLATermData, function (key, value) {
                    $("select[name='SLATerm']").change(function() {
                        if ( $("select[name='SLATerm']").val() == value.SLATerm ) {
                            $("input[name='SLACost']").val(value.SLACost);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the Laravel controller for the API:

```
/**
    ** KPI API
    **/
    public function fetchSLA()
    {
        $kpiTerms = KPITerms::get(['SLATerm' => 'SLATerm', 'SLACost' => 'SLACost']);
        return response()->json([
            'SLATermData' => $kpiTerms, // SLATermData is the name that will be used in Ajax.
        ]);
    }
```